# convert bool to int?

Tags: c#, operands

I have this code, and I can't see why I cannot use the operator || in this example.

"Operator '||' cannot be applied to operands of type 'bool' and 'int'"

Am I missing something? where is this boolean?

```
int i = 1;                            
if ( i == 1)
{
    Response.Write("-3");
}
else if (i == 5 || 3) //this is the error, but where is the bool?
{
    Response.Write("-2");
}
```

Comment: Do it like this 
`else if (i == 5 ||i == 3)`

Comment: Sorry #2, c#.NET here. 

and of course, thank you. I haven't been using these tools for months, getting a bit rusty obviously.

Comment: The details on your answer depend on your programming language, but the fundamental problem is that you are comparing i == 5 (which will evaluate to a boolean true or false) to 3, which is an int.  In some languages, this would work just fine, but probably not in the way you are wanting it to.  Anton's comment above probably addresses what you are trying to do.

Comment: `5 || 3` is a bool. `i == 5` is a bool. Either way you parse it, it makes no sense.

Comment: By the way, I'll make sure not to make this noob mistake again, I had misunderstood the datatypes. I will look into it again, but thank you. It works of course with     else if (i == 5 ||i == 3)

Answer (score 3):

You need to compare x to y and/or x to z, comparing x to (y or z) isn't allowed in most languages. The bool was introduced when you added the "3" which is an int.  The compiler thinks you want (i == 5) || (3) which won't work because 3 does not automatically convert to bool (except maybe in JavaScript).

```
int i = 1;                            
        if ( i == 1)
        {
            Response.Write("-3");
        }


        else if (i == 5 || i == 3) //this is the error, but where is the bool?
        {
            Response.Write("-2");
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also use a switch-statement. Case 3 And 5 are the same
Example

```
int i = 1;

        switch (i)
        {
            case 1:
                Response.Write("-3");
                break;
            case 3:
            case 5:
                Response.Write("-2");
                break;
        }
```

Hope this Helps

Answer (score 1):

The reason why you are getting an error is because you are attempting to perform a boolean evaluation on something doesn't resolve into a boolean equation:

```
if (false || 3)
```

Here '3' does not evaluate to a boolean equation.

If you were to change it to

```
if (false || 3 == 3)
```

Then you will find that it will work.